# C# Code to replace XML

Tags: c#, xml

Hi could anyone please help me to generate a C# code to replace existing XML file using the values of my Datagridview. I really appreciate your help and thank you.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<Site>
  <ItemData Number="one" />
  <ItemData Number="two" />
  <ItemData Number="three" />
</SITE>
```

DatagridViewvalue :

I want to replace it with the value "Item Number". I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
    ProductID   Item Number Cash Value
      3221      4            300
      3221      5            400
      3221      6            500``
```

Comment: How are you saving the XML? Have you looked into XML serialization? It might be easier to just update the values in code and then serialize it to a file.

Comment: Hi, I'm planning to save it using below code :     using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile, true))
                            {
                                writer.Write(secdata);
                            }

Comment: Oh. Yeah, it's going to be rough trying to edit it with a StreamWriter. Try looking into `XmlDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>" +
                "<Site>" +
                  "<ItemData Number=\"one\" />" +
                  "<ItemData Number=\"two\" />" +
                  "<ItemData Number=\"three\" />" +
                "</Site>";

            XDocument site = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            List<XElement> itemDatas = site.Descendants("ItemData").ToList();

            int newNumber = 3;
            foreach (XElement itemData in itemDatas)
            {
                XAttribute number = itemData.Attribute("Number");
                number.Value = newNumber++.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Hi thanks it works but could you give me an example on how it works with XML file in your code you  did it through string. Thank you

Comment: Use XDocument.Load("filename") instead of Parse.